Get the creator of a live video on a Facebook page using the Graph API
I want to check who has created a live video on a Facebook page using the Graph API. When I access the feed and select the 'from' field (https://graph.facebook.com/20.0//live_videos?fields=from), it shows that the creator is the same as the page name. I also tried to get the video ID and then find the admin_creator, but it doesn't give me anything. Any ideas on how I can find out who created the live video?
To check the creator of a live video on a Facebook page using the Graph API.
